# Depricated API and Serialization

Tags: java

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class AppletParamDemo extends Applet
{
    String p,c;
    public void init()
    {
        p=getParameter("place");
        c=getParameter("college");
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString(c,80,20);
        g.drawString(p,100,40);
    }
}
```

The program above does not even compile. While compiling it shows

> Haneefs-MacBook-Pro:javapg Haneef$ javac AppletParamDemo.java
>   Note: AppletParamDemo.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

After recompiling with -Xlint:

> Haneefs-MacBook-Pro:javapg Haneef$ javac AppletParamDemo.java -Xlint
>   AppletParamDemo.java:4: warning: [deprecation] Applet in java.applet has been deprecated
>       public final class AppletParamDemo extends Applet
>                                                  ^
>   AppletParamDemo.java:4: warning: [serial] serializable class AppletParamDemo has no definition of serialVersionUID
>       public final class AppletParamDemo extends Applet
>                    ^
>   2 warnings

What do I do?

Comment: `ls *.class` - warnings are not errors. Now that you've compiled it, how do you plan to run it?